# Can I make the .NET Chart control display data when mouse hovers over?

Tags: c#, charts, mousehover

I am trying to do some charting in my of my C#.NET applications using the .NET Chart Control. 
Is there a way to make a popup that shows the exact data point that the cursor is over when it is hovering over the chart?

Comment: Can you use Tooltip property? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489231.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Check the MapArea class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.maparea.aspx

It'll let you create maps that apply to different areas of the chart and contain their own tooltip.